# How can I install chess engines in windows?

Tags: engines, recommendations, windows

Actually, I want to install top 10 chess engines in my PC for practicing better.

Comment: Why do you think the top 10 engines will help you practice better? One is plenty - and for many humans it is arguably one too many given the ease with which they are abused.

Comment: Actually, I want to make a combination of several engines because I prefer to watch matches among them. It seems very pretty to me when I'm in leisure, particularly in weekend.

Answer (score 5):

I would  recommend Stockfish, currently the world's best chess engine. You can download it [here](https://stockfishchess.org/) for free (but wait first!). However, if you want to practice against it (presumably by playing games) you will need to play against a lower level unless you enjoy getting the life squeezed out of you by an engine that's at least 1000 rating points higher.

However, if you don't want to have to play against Stockfish by typing in a bunch of uci commands into the terminal you should consider not actually downloading Stockfish but downloading [Lucas Chess](https://lucaschess.pythonanywhere.com/downloads), which comes with a niceGUI and an easy way to control the engine's level.

If you really insist on playing against Stockfish in the terminal for some reason, you can find more info about that [here](https://gist.github.com/aliostad/f4470274f39d29b788c1b09519e67372).

Comment: I've installed Lucas Chess but I don't know how can I analyze my Fide Games there?

Comment: A nice alternative to Lucas is also SCID vs. PC (a bit more advanced, but free just like it).

Answer (score 2):

- [Stockfish](https://stockfishchess.org/download/)
- [Lc0](https://lczero.org/play/download/)
- [Dragon](https://komodochess.com/)
- [Berserk](https://github.com/jhonnold/berserk)

You can use most of these and more on [Chessify](https://chessify.me/). Also, most people who are serious about chess use [Chessbase](https://en.chessbase.com/) which will also get you [Fritz](https://fritz.chessbase.com/en/Fritz). If you want to find all the top 10, go to the [TCEC](https://tcec-chess.com/) and check out the latest standings. You will see that for the most part, if you have SF and Lc0, you have the [two top engines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Top_Chess_Engine_Championship).